# WordPress Post Image Size

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am following along with a video course that was made a few years back so some of the code doesn't match exactly with the instructor and when he changes the post image style in the stylesheet it did not change my image (the image is too big).

On the stylesheet he changed it from:

```
    .post-image { height: auto; } to .post-image img { height: auto; }
```

but it did nothing.

So I tried looking for an answer and found a few and tried adding this to my functions.php:

```
add_image_size( 'singlepost-thumb', 1024, 1024 );
```

and then in the content.php:

```
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { //check for feature image ?><div class="post-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'singlepost-thumb' ); ?></div><!-- post-image --><?php } ?>
```

and it changed it to where the image is behind the post excerpt text - which is no good. I don't want it to be a set image size but I do want it to fit on the post excerpt page correctly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

[Blog Excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdd9Z.jpg)

Comment: Can you please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I saw that I messed up and edited it - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add custom image size in functions.php it will affect only the new uploading images.. it will not affect the old images.. in this case use `Regenerate thumbnail plugin`  to change the old image size..

Comment: I did that, but it still has the image behind the text. 

Comment: Do you have screen shot?

Comment: I added it to the bottom of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what fixed this issue - maybe the regenerate thumbnail plugin. But the images look fine now. Thanks!